# Automate container creation from python

Tags: python, docker

I'm using python to create templates of docker projects, it is working fine until the very last step when I want to build the container to create the image. The project structure I have so far is similar to this:

```
project
  |--flask_server.py
  |--main_script.py
  |--image_creator.sh
  |--Dockerfile
  |--requirements.txt
```

My issue is with the file: image_creator.sh, which basically has:

```
docker build -t my_project:latest .
```

That can't be executed without sudo. This is what I have tried so far in the python script, create_contaner.py,  which have the following code:

```
import os
import subprocess
...
...
subprocess.call(['image_creator.sh'])
```

1)

```
python create_contaner.py
```

2)

```
 sudo python create_contaner.py
```

3)

```
sudo su
python create_contaner.py
```

For all three cases I get:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'image_creator.sh'
```

For the last one

I have also tried adding my current user to the group that can run docker without using sudo as explained [here](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/use-docker-without-sudo-ubuntu/)

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

After doing it from the terminal I can execute:

```
docker build -t my_project:latest .
```

Which works with sudo, but if from that user I open python and try:

```
python create_contaner.py
```

I still get the same error. Someone has pointing me to use docker-compose instead of docker build, that that does not seem to get rid of the issue of the permissions.

Comment: did you set `chmod +x  image_creator.sh`?

Comment: Rigth, that seems to work if I do it manually. Can I automate:'chmod +x image_creator.sh '  from python? otherwise I get the same issue but with a different file

Comment: @Adiii got it, you can add that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set permission to your bash script before call the script in python

```
 chmod +x image_creator.sh
```

If you want to automate, you can set permission to file from python

```
import os

command = os.popen('chmod +x image_creator.sh')
print(command.read())
print(command.close())
```

or you check better answer to run bash in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python)